# Razor Pages TryUpdateModelAsync update all fields except X

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a basic razor pages edit page with a form. I am using `TryUpdateModelAsync` to update the model and persisting it to a database.

```
var userToUpdate = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<User>(
   userToUpdate,
   "user",
   e => e.X, e => e.Y, e => e.Z ))
{
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return Page();
}
```

However, my user entity has over 50 fields. Instead of manually typing out all the user fields (and potentially making mistakes), is there a way where I can update all the fields except a few? :

```
TryUpdateModelAsync<User>(
   userToUpdate,
   "user",
   e !=> e.SecretField
))
```

I am aware that I could make a user VM, but I don't want to have that duplication in my codebase.

Comment: Maybe have a look at AutoMapper: https://automapper.org/

Comment: @RoarS. Thanks, but is there no built in way to do this? That would be preferable.

Comment: I'm afraid not. You have an instance of type X, and want to copy that to type Y, hence you'll need some code that can do the job.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I'll just go with the VM strategy.

Comment: AutoMapper will do most of the job for you, as long as property names match.